# Excel compare columns and print value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to Excel so this is probably a rookie mistake but I'm stuck.

Basically I want a formula which matches data from column A with column B. If a match is found, then print into column C (at the same line as column A) data from column D (at the same line as column B).

Here are some mathematical examples:

> If A1 = B3 then C1 = D3

or

> If A5 = B2 then C5 = D2

I have tried looking this up on the net but my limited knowledge of Excel is a problem. The furthest I have come is this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3,0)),"",D1)
```

This seems to see if A1 matches with any line in column B, and if it does, print D1 in C1. This is not what I want.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Function VLOOKUP is what you should use.

In following code, I assume that data is filled in range $A$1:$D$100.

Function to cell C1 is as follows (if all data in A column matchs some in B column)

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$D$100,3,false)
```

This function means:

search value of cell "A1" from $B$1:$B:$100, and pick value of cell in third column('D') of matched row.

You can copy this formula from cell C1 and past to C2:C100 to finish your work.

If some data in A column does not match any data in B Column, use function follows

```
=if(iserror(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$D$100,3,false)),"NOT MATCH",VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$D$100,3,false))
```

Vlookup returns error if no match found, so returns "NOT MATCH" in the case.

Comment: If the OP is using a version of Excel that is 2007 or higher, then `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, $B$1:$D$100, 3, FALSE), "No match")` would be a better formula to handle non-matches. Remove *No matches* and leave an empty set of quotes (e.g. "") to make the cell appear empty.

Comment: That formula does work, thanks a lot for that. However I have a new problem. I changed $D$100 to 1000 because I have well over 100 rows in my table, but vlookup stops working at row 100. Is this a limitation of vlookup and if so is there another way I could do it?

Comment: VLOOKUP works as many rows as the Excel can handle, i.e. upto 65535 by Excel 2003 or older, and over one million by Excel 2007 or newer.  What does "vlookup stops working at row 100" means?  Did you copy contents of cell "C1" to all cells of column C?  If you have 1234 rows of data, you should copy this formula from cell C1 and past to C2:C1234 to finish your work.

Comment: You could also use the reference to the whole column instead of a fixed area: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, $B:$D, 3, FALSE), "No match")` Usually, the extra time it takes isn't noticeable until you start having 100k lines and higher.